# Vuex helper methods for mutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In Vuex, I have my mutations object as follows:

```
 mutations: {
     someMethod(){
        this.someReusableCode();
     },
     anotherMethod(){
        this.someReusableCode();
     },
     someReusableCode(){
       ...
     }
 }
```

However, I'm getting an error that `someReusableCode()` isn't defined.  Where is the best place to define my `someReusableCode()` method so this will work?

Answer (score 3):

You could define a shared method off the `store` object (instance of `Vuex.Store`).

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) { this.inc(state) },
    decrement(state) { this.dec(state) }
  }
})

// Shared functions of store
store.inc = state => state.count++;
store.dec = state => state.count--;
```

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) { this.inc(state) },
    decrement(state) { this.dec(state) }
  }
})

// Shared functions: inc() and dec()
store.inc = state => state.count++
store.dec = state => state.count--

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    count() {
      return store.state.count
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment () {
      store.commit('increment')
    },
    decrement () {
      store.commit('decrement')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ count }}</p>
  <p>
    <button @click="increment">+</button>
    <button @click="decrement">-</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks and I like your solution, however in our case we are using a file structure so that we're defining the Vuex parameter object in its own `store.js` file using `export default {}`, and then in our main-vue.js file we're doing `import store_object from store.js' and then `let store = new Vuex.Store(store_object);`.  I would prefer to keep the helper methods in `store.js`.  I did find that adding the helper methods outside of the object in store.js works, but not sure if this is the best idea.  Any feedback on that strategy would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the helper methods inside store.js.
Just do this:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  helperMethods: {
    inc: (input, increment) => input + increment
  mutations: {
    incrementByFive(state) { state.count = this.helperMethods.inc(state.count,5) },
  }
})
```

Comment: didn't work for me. this.helperMethods is undefined

Comment: I did manage to get this to work with `const helperMethods` - and using `helperMethods.inc` (no `this`)

Comment: This is the right answer, but yes, I had to deviate from the above solution, answer below, but with Vue3:
const helperMethods = {
      hexToRgb(hex) {
        var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
        return result ? {
          r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
          g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
          b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
        } : null;
      },
};

Calling from mutation: RGB=helperMethods.hexToRgb(state.Theme[ThemeKeys[x]])

Answer (score 1):

@siem simonis has the right answer, though with Vue3 I did it this way:

```
const helperMethods = {
componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
  },
  rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + this.componentToHex(r) + this.componentToHex(g) + this.componentToHex(b);
  },
  hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
      r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
      g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
      b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
  },};
```

Then to call the helper:

```
RGB=helperMethods.hexToRgb(state.Theme[ThemeKeys[x]])
```

And you do not need to add it to you export at the end of your store, just FYI.